# Bash - Array length (assignment) of Local Variable vs Global Variable

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, replace

I have the following script:

*For simplicity I removed the replace variables to show the current behaviour easier:*

```
  declare -a CHARACTERS_SEARCHFOR=("-" ".")
  declare -a CHARACTERS_REPLACEWITH=("X" "Y")

  function replacerCharacters(){
      local searchers="${CHARACTERS_SEARCHFOR[@]}"
      local searchers2="${CHARACTERS_SEARCHFOR}"

      echo "Count Original: ${#CHARACTERS_SEARCHFOR[@]}"
      echo "Count Assigned: ${#searchers[@]}"
      echo "Count Assigned Alternative: ${#searchers2[@]}"

      echo "Content Original: ${CHARACTERS_SEARCHFOR[@]}"
      echo "Content Assigned: ${searchers[@]}"
      echo "Content Assigned Alternative: ${searchers2[@]}"
  }
```

replacerCharacters

This gives me the following output:

```
  Count Original: 2
  Count Assigned: 1
  Count Assigned Alternative: 1
  Content Original: - .
  Content Assigned: - .
  Content Assigned Alternative: -
```

Clearly `$searchers2` syntax is incorrect, which I expected but used it to test why `$searchers` return **one item** but *"visually" has the same output as the array.*

How do I correctly assign a local variable to receive array as input?

I would like to do something like this in the end: *supply arguments by command-line preferrably --- but I assume giving an array on command-line might be different*

```
  function replacerCharacters(){
     local searchers="$1"
     local replacers="$2"

     for index in "${!searchers[@]}"; do
        itemSearch="${searchers[$index]}"
        itemReplace="${replacers[$index]}"
     done
  }

  replacerCharacters "${SOME_OTHER_ARRAY[@]}" "${SOME_OTHER_REPLACERS[@]}"
```

Comment: This `local searchers="${CHARACTERS_SEARCHFOR[@]}"` doesn't make `searchers` an array copy of `CHARACTERS_SEARCHFOR`. You need `local searchers=("${CHARACTERS_SEARCHFOR[@]}")` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I correctly assign a local variable to receive array as input?

It doesn't matter whether the variables are local or global. In both cases, use parentheses like you would do in a manual array definition.

```
array=("${otherArray[@]}")
```

> Supply arguments by command-line preferrably --- but I assume giving an array on command-line might be different

You can supply one array just fine

```
f() {
  local x=("$@")
  declare -p x
}
a=(1 2 3)
f "${a[@]}"
```

But for multiple arrays (as in `f "${a[@]}" "${b[@]}"`) there is a problem. The function does not know where the first array ends and the second array starts. You could

- indicate the start/end by specifying the length of the first array

```
f() {
  local xlen="$1";
  shift
  x=("${@:1:xlen}") y=("${@:xlen+1}")
  declare -p x y
}
...
f "${#a[@]}" "${a[@]}" "${b[@]}"
```

- indicate the start/end by inserting a delimiter (`f "${a[@]}" , "${b[@]}"`) which must not appear in the arrays.

```
f() {
  local dpos=$(printf %s\\0 "$@" | grep -zFxnm1 DELIM | sed 's/:.*//');
  x=("${@:1:dpos-1}") y=("${@:dpos+1}")
  declare -p x y
}
...
f "${a[@]}" DELIM "${b[@]}"
```

- do not pass the arrays, but [only their names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63520100/6770384) (`f a b`).

Comment: Thanks didn't even think of trying `()` because I don't think the meaning is always clear in all contexts.  Thanks for showing multiple arrays as arguments, as expected quite complicated. (Pre Bash-4.2)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass multiple arrays as arguments, you have to pass these as name-reference (Bash's `nameref`) or all contained values are expanded as individual arguments.

Nameref variables are supported by Bash 4.2+

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a CHARACTERS_SEARCHFOR=("-" ".")
declare -a CHARACTERS_REPLACEWITH=("X" "Y")

replacerCharacters(){
  # searches and replacers are nameref variables
  local -n searchers="$1"
  local -n replacers="$2"

  for index in "${!searchers[@]}"; do
    itemSearch="${searchers[$index]}"
    itemReplace="${replacers[$index]}"
  done
}

# Pass arrays as names
replacerCharacters SOME_OTHER_ARRAY SOME_OTHER_REPLACERS
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very easy solution for more recent Bashes.  I tried it and works perfectly. (Some of the environments used and testing here are older bash versions).  As the other answer also assisted me with older bash versions, I think that answer is more generic.